# Make static file accessible to only my app hosted on either AWS or Google Cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, static-site

I have a static site (purely HTML, JS & CSS) I will be hosting on either AWS or Google Cloud.

The site pulls data from a CSV that can either be located as a local file on the site, or preferably, on another endpoint.

My issue is, the client does not want the CSV file to be publicly accessible (people shouldn't be able to directly get to it, and download it).

The file needs to live on AWS S3 or Google Cloud Storage, as the client will be updating it periodically.

However, I can't seem to work out how to make it visible to my app, but not if you try to visit the file directly.  I can either make it public, so my app can see it, but then so can everyone else.  Or make it not public, so it can't be downloaded, but then my app also can't see it.

My question is - is what I'm trying to achieve even possible?  Or does the CSV have to either be public or not?

My ideal option would be two separate buckets, one with my static site on, the other, with the CSV files.

Any suggestions would be most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for isn't really possible in the way you've described it. If the CSV is to be consumed directly by the web page, then the web page needs to be able to get it, and if the web page can get it then so can anyone who can view the page. The same is true of any data that is on a web page. Is there a particular reason why you don't want the CSV to be accessed directly? It wouldn't be something you could just go to, you'd have to know the URI (which would be easy to find, but most users wouldn't bother). Are there things in the data that shouldn't be exposed? If so, you need to rethink your approach entirely.

Comment: This is the correct answer, I would only add that if the page doesn't work without the CSV, and you don't want anyone to get at the CSV, then you should consider having authentication in place to protect the page and the CSV - but even then, authenticated users will still be able to get to the CSV if they are the least bit savvy.

Comment: Thanks Jason. I had a feeling that might be the answer,  but wasn't sure if there was some kind of authentication that could be added (similar to how CORS works).

Answer (score 0):

AWS recently released new S3 features that can help with your need. One is Amazon S3 Access Point (https://aws.amazon.com/s3/features/access-points). The other is called Amazon S3 Object Lambda (https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/aws/introducing-amazon-s3-object-lambda-use-your-code-to-process-data-as-it-is-being-retrieved-from-s3/).

It looks like you can put Lambdas in front of an S3 bucket to process and transform requests to its files (also known as "objects"). Unfortunately, I do not have a precise answer to your question as I have never implemented this solution but I believe that you might be able to store the CSV file in S3 and give access to your static site only thanks to an S3 Access Point.

Alternatively, you might be able to use CloudFront and Lambda Associations to also restrict access to your CSV files to specific origins.